# How to share my files via LAN?

Tags: 14.04, files, lan, ip, sharing

I would like to share my files via LAN.

How to know IP address of mine and other's one by using terminal or anything else but without using Internet?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest a tool called [NitroShare](http://nitroshare.net/).

Install it and it will instantly recognize any other computers on your LAN that are also running NitroShare, even if they're Windows or OS X. You don't even have to know the other IP address.

Basically all you do is launch the program, then click on the icon in the upper-right-hand-corner and choose <kbd>Send Files</kbd> or <kbd>Send Directory</kbd> & choose the file or directory to send.

Then you choose the destination and bam - it's underway.

It also makes very good use of your network bandwidth, so the transfers are nice and quick.

This tool currently only works with a GUI, but terminal control is planned - making it even more useful for servers and headless machines.

Comment: Is there any command to check the IP address of someone's which i have connected?

Answer (score 0):

ifconfig maybe help?

```
vodka@vodka-PC:~$ ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0xxxxx
inet addr:192.168.1.37  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

My IP - 192.168.1.37